# Stuck in a request with response 205

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

My server can send me a status code **205** when I should clean the data of my application.

However, the request gets stuck without receiving a successful or error response from the afnetworking, until it gives me an errorof time out

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo=0x7fea70e85210 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fea70e5d180 "The request
>   timed out."

This is the info about the request:

[image]

I am using a simple AFHTTPSessionManager client to the requests.

```
self.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
self.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

NSMutableSet *contentTypes = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithSet:self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes];
[contentTypes addObject:@"text/html"];
[contentTypes addObject:@"application/json"];
[contentTypes addObject:@"text/json"];
[contentTypes addObject:@"text/plain"];

self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = contentTypes;
```

My Request

```
 [self POST:apiService parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

   NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
    if (response.statusCode == 205) {
        if (block) {
            block(nil,nil);
        }
    }else{
        if (block) {
            block(dictionary,nil);
        }
    }

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    if (block) {
        block(nil,error);
    }
}];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend the timeout duration, e.g.

```
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:20.0];
```

Looks like `AFNetworking` had some issue related to timeouts described [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1897)

P.S. Show some code

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But honestly i don t think the time is the problem.. The server sent the response imediatly.. And if i change the status code from the server the problem disapear..

Comment: Would be better if you post some code for further assistance